# R:: Return the First Occurence of a Variable in a Row as New Column

Tags: r, function, character, apply

I have been fumbling badly with the apply function. I have a list of single character values and would like to return the first mention of a vowel.

```
a<- c("A","B","C","E")
b<- c("O","T","D","J")
c<- c("A","R","B","K")
d<- c("F","L","O","U")
e<- c("N","D","S","Z")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I'd like to create a new column that returns the first instance of a vowel for that row.

```
vow <- c("A","E","I","O","U")
```

The result would be (A,NA?,O,E), how would you handle if no value is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and will give you a warning if no letters is found. You can elaborate the function to catch this as well.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x, vow) x[min(which(x %in% vow))], vow = vow)
[1] "A" NA  "O" "E"
```

Comment: Really like the simplicity in this. I'll expand this example a lot, what's the significance of vow=vow at the end?

Comment: That's just explicitly passing on the argument to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

```
> m <- apply(df, 1, match, table=vow)
> 
> i <- apply(m, 2, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])
> 
> vow[i]
[1] "A" NA  "O" "E"
```

In three steps:

1) Apply match to each row, get a table of indexes (transposed!)

2) Get the first non-NA from each column

3) look up index in vow

Comment: This is really interesting and going to be useful. I sometimes need the second value and this is perfect way to get these. Thanks!

Comment: Then change na.omit(x)[1] to [2] :)

Comment: How would you get the last? [-1]?

Comment: tail(...,1) would do it. [-1] will be all except the 1st.